# Rewrite all requests to index.php except certain subdirectory requests

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to rewrite all requests to `/index.php`, except `/css/*` and `/js/*`.

This is my original config

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

which works, but lets me access all files directly. I tried this

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php break;
}
```

but couldn't get past weird errors like PHP parsing breaking. After I get `/index.php` rewrite working I assume I should do something like `location /css/ { .. }` etc, but I'm not really sure.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually found an answer right after I posted this question.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}

location /css/ {}
location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

The trick seemed to be to put the php `location` above the other ones.